# How to discover the file that contains a CSS definition

Tags: html, css

I am dealing with a complex page with a lot of CSS files (that were not created by me). I am fighting with a CSS style that is not on the more obvious places (css files) that I can find and I don't have a clue where it is being define.

Is there any tool available that can tell me the file where a particular property of a class or id is being defined (having in mind that this property can be inherit from other definition)?

Comment: What's about Developer Tools? You can see where styles are defined by clicking the grey text with the name of the file, and it will bring you right there.

Comment: what browser are you talking about? Safari and Firefox are not showing anything.

Comment: Sorry, in Chrome. Who's developing in Safari anyway? :D

Comment: @pzin Can you explain what the problem is with Safari?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome Devtools enables you to quickly do this.

[image: Chrome Devtools]